# Invalid column name (JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I've been trying to fix my code for quite some time now. I can't find what i'm missing here. I've tried many things. Replacing names, changing SELECT statement from, for example, `SELECT name ... FROM wage_java A " to "SELECT a.name ... FROM wage_java A`. That doesn't seem to help me. SQLDeveloper always gives me one output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnbCI.png
Hope someone can help me.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class WageK{
    public static void getWage (int w_id, java.lang.String[] w_name, 
    java.lang.String[] w_lname, int[] w_wage, int[] w_mnr, int[] wages_calc)
  throws SQLException {
        try{
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:"); 
          PreparedStatement pstmt = null;  
          ResultSet rs = null;

          java.lang.String sql = "Select a.name, a.last_name, a.wage, a.month_nr, 
          Value(A).wages_calc() as emp_wage " + "From wage_java A " + "Where A.ID = ?";
          pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pstmt.setInt(1, w_id); 
          rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

          if (rs.next()) { 
              w_name[0] = rs.getString("name");
              w_lname[0] = rs.getString("last_name");
              w_wage[0] = rs.getInt("wage");
              w_mnr[0] = rs.getInt("month_nr");
              wages_calc[0] = rs.getInt("wages_calc");
          } else {
              w_name[0] = "0";
              w_lname[0] = "0";
              w_wage[0] = 0;
              w_mnr[0] = 0;
              wages_calc[0] = 0;        
          }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

PL/SQL wrapper :

```
Create or replace procedure getWage (w_id IN NUMBER, nm OUT VARCHAR2, 
lnm OUT VARCHAR2, wg OUT NUMBER, mnth OUT NUMBER, 
wages_calc OUT NUMBER) AS language Java name 'WageK.getWage
(int, java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],int[], int[], int[])';
```

Trying to get the data out:

```
set serveroutput ON;
call  DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(2000);

declare
nm VARCHAR2(20);
lnm VARCHAR2(20);
wg Number;
mnth Number;
wages_calc Number;

BEGIN
  getWage(1, nm, lnm, wg, mnth, wages_calc);
  dbms_output.Put_line('Wage of employees:');
  dbms_output.Put_line('  ' || wages_calc);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wages_calc[0] = rs.getInt("wages_calc");
```

should be

```
wages_calc[0] = rs.getInt("emp_wage");
```

You've provided an alias `emp_wage` in your query so you'd need to use the alias name in your JDBC code if you want to use column names.

Taking a step back, I can't see why you would want to use a Java stored procedure here rather than a PL/SQL stored procedure.  And if you're going to use a Java stored procedure, I don't see why you'd use arrays rather than scalar values-- your PL/SQL wrapper is only returning scalars.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. If you want to know why i'm using Java store procedure - it's a task. I'll look into that scalar values thing you're talking about. Anyway, thank you again. @Justin